# Question based on Lagrange Theorem

Tags: group-theory

The question goes:
Let n be a natural number. Prove that if $G$ is a group of size $n$, and $H\leq G$ is a subgroup of order $n−1$ , then $n=2$.

And my solution to the question is:

Let $G$ be a group of size $n$ (a finite group) and $H\subset G$ be its subgroup of order $n-1$ where $n \in \mathbb N$. By Lagrange’s Theorem, the number of elements of a subgroup of G must completely divide the number of elements of group $G$, that is:

$$ [G:H]=|G|/|H| = n/(n-1) $$

where $[G:H]$  is the Index denoting the number of distinct left cosets of $H$. Let $[G:H]$  be denoted by $k$. From this, it can be stated that $n$ must be greater than 1, that is $n>1$ , since if $n=1$ then the above becomes undefined. Also, $k\neq 0$, since if $k=0$ then $n=0$ but $n$ is a non-zero number, and $k>1$, since if $k=1$ then the above becomes:

$$ 1= n/(n-1)   \implies  n-1=n  \implies   0=1 $$

which is a false statement. Now, $n$ can either be an odd or even natural number. Suppose $n$ is odd, then $n$ can be written as:
$n=2m+1$   where $m \in \mathbb Z$ and $m>0$
Then:

$$ k=n/(n-1)=(2m+1)/(2m+1-1)=(2m+1)/2m=1+1/2m $$

which shows that the index $k$ is not a whole value for any value of $m$. This implies that $|H|$  does not completely divide $|G|$  exhibiting a remainder. This contradicts $|H|$  dividing $|G|$  completely, hence, $n$ is an even number. Now, the only even number that $n$ can be which satisfies:

$$ [G:H]=k=n/(n-1) $$

and its conditions is $2$, thus, $n=2$.

Is my solution appropriate or do I need to make some changes?? If so kindly inform me where... THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very long.

Continuing from here:

> [G:H]=|G|/|H| =n/(n-1)

As you say, the index is the number of distinct left cosets of H.  Thus it is a positive integer.  So $n-1$ divides $n$.

The Euclidean Algorithm implies $\gcd(n,n-1)=1$.  But if $n-1$ divides $n$, then $\gcd(n,n-1)=n-1$.  So we must have $n-1=1$ or $n=2$.